# Minimize method calls - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this method `get_info` when I pass a key and it gives me a value of it.

```
name = self.get_info("name_key")
age = self.get_info("age_key")
gender = self.get_info("gender_key")
hometown = self.get_info("hometown_key")
state = self.get_info("state_key")
```

I need to extract `name, age, gender, hometown, state`.

Is there any way I can get the values in a minimized way (reduce duplicate lines)?

I need to call the method again and again for each value.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: extract from where? can you self.get() the whole dictionary in one call?

Comment: No, this is not possible as keys are stored on a URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a loop along with spread assignment.

```
name, age, gender, hometown, state = [self.get_info(x) for x in ('name_key', 'age_key', 'gender_key', 'hometown_key', 'state_key')]
```

Comment: I need to loop in again to fetch standalone values right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. You'll need something else for values that don't come from `self.get_info()`

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
def new_get_info(keyLists):
    return tuple([self.get_info(key) for key in keyLists])
```

and call:

```
name, age = new_get_info(["name", "age"])
```

Hope this helps. You can query any parameter needed.